# JQuery hover function causes my div to hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my functions.js I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
  $("#cat").hover(function() {
    $("#kiti").show();  
  })
  $("#kiti").mouseout(function() {
    $("#kiti").hide();      
  })                                 
})
```

Html file:

```
<a id="cat" href="#">category</a>
<div id="kiti">
    <a href="#">sub1</a>
    <br /><a href="#">sub2</a>
</div>
```

Why, when I hover over sub1, sub1 and sub2 hide? If it's simple text, it's ok. I hope you got my question.

Edit: By the way. Is there any way to make something like `die();` or `exit();` from php in javascript to stop execution?

Comment: Thanks Chris Farmer for indenting that jQuery code properly

Comment: I wanted to do the same, but I don't know how.

Comment: Tomas - what effect are you trying to accomplish?  When hovering over #cat, you want to show #kiti, and when you mouse out of #kiti, you want to hide #kiti?  So it's kind of a nested and dynamic expanding menu?

Comment: Correct, James. I did that, but when I put mouse pointer on <a href="#">sub1</a> or <a href="#">sub2</a> all subs hides, but it should hide only when I go out of #kiti

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.hover()` takes two arguments. If you just want to use the first, use `$.mouseover()` instead.

```
$(function(){
  $("a#cat").mouseover(function(){
    $("#kiti").show(); // shows <div id="kiti">...sub1...sub2...</div>
  });
  $("#kiti").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide();    // hides <div id="kiti">...sub1...sub2...</div>
  });
});
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that jQuery 1.4 (which is still in Alpha) supports passing just one function to `hover()`.

Comment: It still doesn't work. When I put mouse pointer on <a href="#">sub1</a> all subs hides.

Comment: Unbelievable! It's finally working, thank you so much!
By the way, can you explain, what is the difference between mouseleave and mouseout?

Answer (score 3):

`mouseout` is the wrong event - it is triggered when you hover **over a child element.**
Use `mouseleave` instead:

```
$("#cat").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#kiti").show();  
});
$("#kiti").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#kiti").hide();      
});
```

See it here: http://jsbin.com/irexo
Documentation here: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseout

Comment: Happens all the time. You'll get me next time :)

Comment: Thank you. And can you tell me, what I have to add that when I put away mouse pointer from category instantly?